# Repairing an old Windows computer without install disks

Tags: windows-7, bsod, laptop-repair, filesystem-corruption

I am trying to fix an old HP Pavilion dv9000.
I think the system got corrupted, after different people tried to fix it.

When I start it up the HP logo shows up then this:

[image]

then:

[image]

then:

[image]

then:

[image]

and then it shuts down.

Eventually I get this:

[image]

and then it shuts down. I'm sorry that these are in French, but I think these screens look pretty much the same in every Windows version.

I'm trying to either reinstall a functioning system on it (Windows or other - but I don't have Windows install CDs), diagnose it, or just back it up onto a SD card. Ideally all three.

Comment: you can order restore media for any HP model from HP support. that is usually the best bet. Last time I did it, it cost 20USD to cover disk and shipping.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think I could install an open source system on it?

Comment: I've used debian-based linuxes on dv9000 laptops since 2007, with varying degrees functionality. if your system is already trashed and you've backed up any user files you wish to keep, it can't hurt to try one.

Comment: how is a computer with windows 7 preinstalled on it, an "old computer".

Comment: this guy http://www.techfleece.com/2011/05/06/download-windows-7-repair-disk/  thinks it might still be possible to download a win7 iso legally, in which case you can use the repair feature. You shouldn't really have an OS installed on a computer when you don't have the ISO/DVD/CD for it because you will struggle when you have to repair it.

Comment: Dv9000 had serious video chip/motherboard issues, these models were so poorly constructed there was a class action lawsuit against Nvidia, I would toss it....http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/68770-35-class-action-lawsuit-dv9000

Comment: so i'll just take it apart and get the HD out or something... too bad I wanted to turn it into a renderfarm but since the graphics card seems to be a piece of crap that maybe wouldn't have helped much

Comment: you guys need to make your comments into answers so I can vote and close this thing (looking at you, moab and barlop)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand whether I am even looking at Italian or French, so pardon if the info I am asking for is obvious from the screens.
You are running the "System Restore" procedure that you can get into on HP computers by breaking into the boot(pressing F11 repeatedly)before Windows start up???

Here is a link to show what I am talking about: (HP will be pretty much the same for Vista and windows 7)
http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00809678

If this does not work you are mostly out of luck, unless you can verify that the recovery partition is still there and intact.

Comment: "Starting a recovery from the hard drive and the computer is off" ... maybe i should have mentioned that